# Read content of file and put particular portion of content in separate files using bash

Tags: bash, grep, tail, head

I would like to get specific file contains from single file and put into separate files via bash. I have tried getting test1 file contain using below code and able to get it but i'm failed when getting everything in respected files.

## Tried code:

```
reportFile=/report.txt
test1File=/test1.txt
test2File=/test2.txt
test3File=/test3.txt

totalLineNo=`cat ${reportFile} | wc -l`
test1LineNo=`grep -n "Test1 file content :" ${reportFile} | grep -Eo '^[^:]+'`
test2LineNo=`grep -n "Test2 file content :" ${reportFile} | grep -Eo '^[^:]+'`
test3LineNo=`grep -n "Test3 file content :" ${reportFile} | grep -Eo '^[^:]+'`

exactTest1LineNo=`echo $(( ${test1LineNo} - 1 ))`
exactTest2LineNo=`echo $(( ${test2LineNo} -1 ))`
exactTest3LineNo=`echo $(( ${test3LineNo} -1 ))`

test1Content=`cat ${reportFile} | head -n ${exactTest1LineNo}`
test3Content=`cat ${reportFile} | tail -n ${exactTest3LineNo}`

echo -e "${test1Content}\r" >> ${test1File}
echo -e "${test3Content}\r" >> ${test3File}
```

## report.txt:

```
-------------------------------------

My Report:

Test1 file content:
1
2
3
4
5
6

Test2 file content:
7
8
9
10

Test3 file content:
11
12
13
14
15

Note: Find my report above.

-------------------------------------
```

## test1.txt (expected):

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

## test2.txt (expected):

```
7
8
9
10
```

## test3.txt (expected):

```
11
12
13
14
15
```

Comment: You misuse the `cat` command. Use [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to check your code before posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With single **`awk`** command:

```
awk '/^Test[0-9] file content:/{ f=1; fn=tolower($1)".txt"; next }
     f && NF{ print > fn }!NF{ f=0 }' report.txt
```

Viewing results:

```
$ head test[0-9].txt
==> test1.txt <==
1
2
3
4
5
6

==> test2.txt <==
7
8
9
10

==> test3.txt <==
11
12
13
14
15
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly: you have a long file report.txt and you want to extract short files from it. The name of each file is followed by the string " file content:" in the file report.txt.

This is my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
reportFile=report.txt

Files=`grep 'file content' $reportFile | sed 's/ .*$//'`

for F in $Files ; do
    f=${F,}.txt         # first letter lowercase and append .txt
    awk "/$F file content/,/^\$/ {print}" $reportFile |
        tail -n +2 |    # remove first line with "Test* file content:"
        head -n -1 > $f # remove last blank line
done
```

Comment: I don't write the resulting files in / like you, but in the current directory.

Comment: Thanks Pierre, can you please accept the question as well?